# How to turn on ubuntu pc with remote desktop

Tags: login, remote-desktop

Can i turn on, logout, login one ubuntu pc from another ubuntu pc through remote desktop.
I have also try remote desktop but i can only when pc is turn on.

Comment: If your PC is turned off there's no network connection - hence there's no way to reach the device. However, you might be interested in a feature called [Wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). Note the LAN in the name - it only works on the same *local* network.

Comment: Take a look at this [Post], see if it might help, or get you starting on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

#### Powered off → unreachable.

You'll only be able to connect to your PC whenever it's on, because if it's off, then there's nothing running on the machine to contact to and there's no network active. A device in a powered off state is really off, you see. Similarly - your can't receive phone calls on your mobile phone without it having turned on. Some software can't do magic here.

However, I know of two techniques exist to manage the power without the machine being turned on, although it needs the wall socket power to be connected of course.

- **Wake on LAN**. It's a feature of your network card - it will listen to "magic packets" to arrive on the interface to trigger a "power on" event on the PCI bus. It needs some standby power and another device in the same local network to be able to send such magic packets. So, basically, you'll have to

  1. configure your BIOS to listed to WoL events.
  2. have a network card that supports this.
  3. configure your network card to do so (see manpage of `ethtool`).
  4. have some device connected to the internet fire up the PC by sending the magic packet on the local network.

  Major limitation: no available directly over the internet.

  See also:

  - [Wake-on-lan under Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/210890/88802)
  - [How can I enable wake-on-lan permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47918/88802)
  - [Power Management - Sleep / Wake up Server when accessed](https://askubuntu.com/q/43374/88802)
- **Out of Band management module**. Some motherboards, mostly server and business-line desktop machines feature the Intel vPro with [AMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology). In servers you'll notice most have a dedicated card for this - HP iLO, Dell iDRAC, etc. With such a module you'll be able to control power (and usually more). See the manual of your desktop if you have it and how that works.

  Major limitation: hardware requirements.

After the machine has been powered on with one of the techniques above, you'll have to make sure your remote desktop server (e.g. VNC server, NX server, etc.) is started and the network is automatically connected properly, so you can connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to login the ubuntu pc when it's logoff  same as windows server 2003 works. I have start the cpu and then connect to remote desktop and enter user name and password and login the pc. If is it possible then pls reply me I have really greatful to you for your co-operation.

Comment: **Logged off** is not the same as **powered off**. Ask a new question, please. With Windows you also cannot reach the machine if it's powered off.

Comment: My friend's Ubuntu pc is logged off condition, How can i connect from my ubuntu pc to my friend's pc

Comment: @Rakesh Again: **Ask a NEW question**. Your issue is different from the one you described in your question in a way that editing it would make it a different question.