# How to create a remote desktop connection between two Ubuntu PCs

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a server on a PC, but I am unable to connect via remote desktop from my another Ubuntu PC.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: If this is related to [your other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313327/how-to-turn-on-ubuntu-pc-with-remote-desktop#comment396727_313467), then you should include the specific situation that you want to connect to the system in a *logged off state*.

Comment: I had wrongly ask turn off instead logged off. please understand me and solve my problem

Comment: Yes, exactly. So now make sure you are specific and correct this time and edit your question accordingly. ;)

Comment: Tell me how to connection between two Ubuntu pc via remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

For 12.04 ubuntu on terminal:

1. open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. type in: `vino-preferences`
3. enter
4. Desktop sharing preference
5. make changes as per your need

Answer (score -1):

Here are some steps you can take to establish a remote desktop connection:

1. Open up Remote Desktop Preferences on the computer you want to control.
2. Under Sharing, select Allow other users to view your desktop and Allow other users to control your desktop
3. Open up Remote Desktop Viewer on the controller
4. Select VNC for the protocol and the computer you want to control's IP address for the Host
5. Choose any other options you want and click connect

Comment: Are you sure this works for the target PC in a logged off state? (i.e. from the login screen)

Comment: You will want to change the power settings on the PC to never sleep, so that it keeps Internet enabled.

Comment: Let me put my comment a bit more specific. Your steps are concerning user-specific VNC settings. Will this still work after you have logged out (or before you even logged in)? Have you actually tried that you can control the machine from the login screen? I can't test it right now, but I really think this does not work for the OP.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 12.10, you can connect directly to the login screen for remote access.

Comment: IMO, one should be managing servers either via ssh or webmin. Webmin is a graphical web interface and much better suited to managing servers, and more secure, then VNC.

Comment: @Dillmo Please explain how to do this.